# CSV reader not functional when including Boolean

Tags: java, csv, boolean, reader

Does anyone know why my csv file is not being read when including a Boolean in the reader?
It works without and gives no error when compiling, however it seems like the whole read instruction is being skipped, because the System.out.println also doesn't work.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.net.*;


public class TransportOrderReader {

    public TransportOrder readCsvFile(String aName, int orderID, String regio, String status, Winkel winkel) {
        TransportOrder transportOrder = new TransportOrder(orderID, regio, status, winkel);
        try {
            int lineNr = 0;
            File aFile = new File(aName + ".csv");
            BufferedReader aBr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
            String aLine = "";
            while (aLine != null) {
                aLine = aBr.readLine();
                if (aLine != null) {
                    String [] lineParts = aLine.split(";", -1);
                    if (lineParts.length == 4) {
                        int pakketID = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[0]);
                        int volumePakket = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[1]);
                        int gewichtPakket = Integer.parseInt(lineParts[2]);
                        boolean koeling = Boolean.parseBoolean(lineParts[3]);
                        Pakket pakket = new Pakket(pakketID, volumePakket, gewichtPakket, koeling);
                        transportOrder.addMember(pakket);
                    }
                    else System.out.println("Number of attributes <> 4 on " + lineNr);
                    lineNr++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Aantal gelezen pakketten: " + lineNr);
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
        return transportOrder;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/94-ignoring-exceptions-is-dangerous
Example of lines from file too please

Comment: @g00se examples of lines from the file would be:

123,10,25,FALSE
232,100,50,TRUE

etc

Comment: That wouldn't work with the code you've posted. It would be unparseable

Comment: @g00se Okay, why would that be unparseable? It did work without the boolean, so I assume there is something work with the format of that input?

Comment: Because your code is splitting on semicolons. That file is delimited by commas so it can't be the actual file